# Sending Http Post request returns 500 status code in IoS

Tags: ios, swift, post, https, request

I am trying to send Receipt data of NSData type(converted to string) and several other parameters of type as String in Http Post request.

```
func receiptValidation(productId:String)
    {

             let SUBSCRIPTION_SECRET = My_SecretKey
             let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
             let receiptPath = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL?.path
             if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: receiptPath!){
                 var receiptData:NSData?
                 do{
                     receiptData = try NSData(contentsOf: Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.alwaysMapped)
                 }
                 catch{
                     print("ERROR: " + error.localizedDescription)
                 }
                 let receiptString = receiptData?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                // let base64encodedReceipt = receiptData?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.endLineWithCarriageReturn)
           let requestDictionary = ["receipt-data":receiptString!,"password":SUBSCRIPTION_SECRET]

                 guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(requestDictionary) else {  print("requestDictionary is not valid JSON");  return }
                 do {

                     let requestData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestDictionary)
                   let requestDataString = NSString(data: requestData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

                    //https://<apiProxyServer>:<apiProxyServerPort>/api/validate-receipt-data

                    let URLForApplication:String = String(format:"%@/api/validate-receipt-data",opcodeDetails["apiProxyBaseUrl"]!)  // this works but as noted above it's best to use your own trusted server
                     let url:URL! = URL.init(string: URLForApplication)
                    var request = URLRequest.init(url: url)
                     request.httpMethod = "POST"
                     let configure = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
                    var postString:[String:Any]=[
                        "receiptData": requestDataString
                        "deviceType":"IOS",
                        "subscriberId":encodeString(normalString: defaults.array(forKey: "userDetails")?.first as! String),
                        "password":encodeString(normalString: defaults.array(forKey: "userDetails")?.last as! String),
                        "productId":encodeString(normalString: productId),
                        "code":opcodeDetails["opCode"]!
                    ]
                     do {
                       let receiptData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString)
                         request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                        request.httpBody = receiptData
                       } catch let error {
                           print(error.localizedDescription)
                       }
                let session = URLSession(configuration:configure,
                                          delegate:applicationDelegate.application,
                                          delegateQueue:OperationQueue.main)
                    session1 = session

                 let connection = session1?.dataTask(with: request)

                 connection?.resume()

                 } catch let error as NSError {
                     print("json serialization failed with error: \(error)")
                 }

             }

    }
```

Where encodeString() is a defined method

```
func encodeString(normalString:String) -> String {

        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.letters

        let encodedString:String!=normalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacters)

        return encodedString

    }
```

There were no problem on server side.But I could not get success response instead What I am getting is `{"status":"failure","statusCode":500,"message":"Resource url not found!"}`.What mistake am i doing with this code?.Anyone please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending  `'/'` at the end of URL.

Eg:
 `google.com/api/post` and `google.com/api/post/` are different and trailing slash sometimes gives 500 error, in case of Django-Backend it does.